# Balanced Binary Search Tree Methods

Tags: java, oop, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I'm new to programming and I have an assignment. My homework is related to a balanced binary search tree. I had a few problems with some methods, I would be happy if you could help me. Below are the methods I'm having trouble with.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {
    public Node root;

    // Constructor
    BinarySearchTree() {
        //Write your codes here
        root = null;
    }

    // Insert a key node to Binary-Search-Tree. Make sure that the BST is balanced after inserted operation.
    public void insert(int key) {
        //Write your codes here

    }

    // Delete a key node to Binary-Search-Tree. Make sure that the BST is balanced after deleted operation.
    public void delete(int key) {
        //Write your codes here


    }
```

Comment: This task is too difficult for someone who is new to programming

Comment: I'm a second-year student and I have no idea how to do it. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have also that method, I can use it.

```
private Node buildBalancedBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {
        //Write your codes here
        int mid = (start+end) / 2;
        Node node = new Node(arr[mid]);
        node.leftNode = buildBalancedBST(arr, start, end);
        node.rightNode = buildBalancedBST(arr, start, end);
        return node;


    }
```